# Is the VFS's city relevant from where you apply for a UK visa?

Tags: united-kingdom

Following the completion of my short term work visa, my organization has asked me to return to India to apply for a United Kingdom ICT Tier 2 Long Term work visa. I already have the paperwork ready, and I have to select a VFS centre on the online application. Is it mandatory that I apply from the same city as that of my organization (which would be the VFS Bangalore centre), or can I apply from a VFS in another city in India?

My permanent residence is in Calcutta, and hence I am looking at the option to apply from VFS Calcutta. Do you see any potential problems in applying from a different city than my organization?

Answer (score 4):

[Based on this site](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/applicationcentre.html)

> You should normally apply at the VFS Global visa application centre **in
>   or closest to**, the state in which you are **documented as being
>   resident**. Please contact VFS Global if you have any doubts as to where
>   to make your application.

So if you are a resident in Calcutta (Kolkata) then you should definitely try to get an appointment there. It's details are:

> UK Visa application center, Fifth floor, RENE tower,Plot No. AA-I,
>   1842, Rajdanga Main Road,Kasba, Kolkata 700107
>
> Monday to Friday, 08:00 - 14:00
>
> Passport Collection: Monday to Friday, 15:00 - 17:00

[This site](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/book_appointment.html) describes what you need to bring with you:

> Please **print the email confirming the details of your appointment**, and
>   bring this with you to the visa application centre you have chosen to
>   attend.
>
> You should reach the visa application centre **5 minutes before** your
>   appointment time.
>
> **The appointment must be made in your name.** Another person cannot
>   attend your scheduled appointment.
>
> When you attend the visa application centre, **you will need to provide
>   your biometric information**, which includes a photograph and a digital
>   scan of your fingerprints. *If you have temporary injuries on your
>   fingers, please wait until the injuries heal before your appointment
>   date*. You should also remove any henna on your fingertips, or allow it
>   to fade, as this may prevent us from getting a clear scan.